# In vim, how do I replace a hex character with another hex character

Tags: vim

how can I replace a hex with another hex value?
for example, I want to replace `\x09` with `\x10`, I tried

```
:s/\\%x09/\x10/g
:s/\\%x09/\\%x10/g
```

but neither worked.

The first parameter `\\%x09` is correct, and the issue is in the second parameter.

Comment: What is an hex character? (Yes, I know hex means hexadecimal.) Show a possible input file.

Comment: In your example, `<C-A>` does it.

Comment: https://vi.stackexhange.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The first parameter `\\%x09` is correct, and the issue is in the second parameter.

No, `\\%x09` is not correct, it should be `\%x09`.

If you take a look at `:help :s` you will notice that the first part ("search") of a substitution is a *pattern*, but the second part ("replace") is a *string*, which means that you can't use a regular expression, there, and thus that something like:

```
:s/\%x09/\x10/g
```

can only be expected to replace the matching character with three: a `x`, a `1`, and a `0`, which is not what you want.

One possible solution could be to use `:help printf()` in a `:help sub-replace-expression`. Something like this:

```
:s/\%x09/\=printf("\x10")/g
```